# Html to php var + parsing + Wordpress -> get_the_excerpt()

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I guess this is a problem of parsing but couldn't figure it out after few hours on it. I am close to the solution but stuck and starting to drive me crazy!

**The issue:** I can't get my excerpt (description) dynamically as it looks like my variable ***$my_id*** is returning null when I am pushing it into the function *get_the_excerpt()*

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
    {{ data[ index ].option_id }}
<?php $my_id = ob_get_clean(); ?>

<?php $product_description = get_the_excerpt($my_id); ?>
<span class="radio_button_desc"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_composited_product_excerpt', wpautop( do_shortcode( wp_kses_post( $product_description ) ) ), $product_id, $component_id, $composite ); ?></span>
```

I have already tried to push the id directly like the following:

```
<?php $product_description = get_the_excerpt(123456); ?>
```

And guess what? It's working.

I also tried to **parse** *$my_id* to an **(int)**. My *gettype()* is returning it as an int but my variable return "0" in that case.

***echo $my_id*** is returning the right numbers (id) so I can't get why it doesn't work when I push it through my variable inside  **get_the_excerpt($my_id);**

Any clue on it?

Cheers!

**EDIT 1:**

I've updated my code with a *vardump*  & *print_r* to see the return.

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
    {{ data[ index ].option_id }}
<?php $my_id = ob_get_clean(); ?>
<?php var_dump($my_id); ?>
<?php $product_description = get_the_excerpt( $my_id ); ?>
<?php print_r(get_the_excerpt( $my_id )); ?> <!-- return nothing */ -->
<span class="radio_button_desc"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_composited_product_excerpt', wpautop( do_shortcode( wp_kses_post( $product_description ) ) ), $product_id, $component_id, $composite ); ?></span>
```

**Output:**

[image: Output string]

**Output** when I parse it to an **integer** by adding *$my_id = is_int($my_id) ? $my_id : (int) $my_id;* :
[image: Output Int]

This is basically returning me the excerpt of my actual post and **not dynamically with the id of $my_id**.

Answer (score 0):

My thought is there is extra white space characters breaking your string to int conversion:

```
get_the_excerpt( trim( $my_id ) );
```

or possibly:

```
get_the_excerpt( (int) trim( $my_id ) );
```

or remove the whitespacing between the output buffering functions:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>{{ data[ index ].option_id }}<?php $my_id = ob_get_clean(); ?>
```

but I feel the first is safer.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I already tried this and whenever I remove these extra white space it's giving me (not dynamically from the id) the excerpt of my product.
So I guess when I remove these spaces, that return me $my_id blank so "get_the_excerpt()"... and not get_the_excerpt($my_id);

Comment: I've updated/edited my question and added some screenshot of the output.

Comment: Your screenshot var_dump shows a string of 45 characters for `string(45) " 1904463 "` whitespace galore. Compare `var_dump($my_id);` to `var_dump(trim($my_id));` View your browser source to confirm the whitespace.

Comment: Ok I did it. The output is now string(29) which correlate with: `{{ data[ index ].option_id }}` **-> 29 char**
So I guess the error is coming here, looks like it's not taking the return from the `{{ data[ index ].option_id }}`. I don't get why though as when I `echo` / `print_r` / `var_dump` my number is returned.

Comment: It's possible that what you're seeing is actually being processed AFTER your code has executed by another filter?

Comment: I don't think so, because in the same .php file I have also this code above. Please have a look there: [link](https://eshoes.com.au/product/composite-test-001/) with the credentials: user01 / 123456
If you inspect, you have for intance the _<div id=component_option_radio_button_**1904466**_
Here is where is code is use "above" so it should work when I pick it with the **ob_get** right?

Answer (score 0):

One slightly academic thing worth noting here: we always get a string type value from ob_get_clean (or ob_get_contents). Because PHP is loosely typed and therefore doesn’t typically make a noise about this sort of thing, it’ll happily make that string '1' into a number by add 0 to it.

You can do any of the below.

```
$my_id = $my_id + 0;
```

OR

```
$my_id = (int) $my_id;
```

OR better

```
$my_id = is_int($my_id) ? $my_id : (int) $my_id;
```

Comment: I already tried the 2 first solutions but it didn't work. Same as above whenever I parse it's giving me (not dynamically from the id) the excerpt of my product. So when I parse to "int" the **echo $my_id return me 0**, So I guess because $my_id is blank it's calling "get_the_excerpt()"... and not get_the_excerpt($my_id);

Comment: write,  `ob_start();
the_ID();
$id = ob_get_clean();`

Comment: Doesn't work as the_ID(): is returning the ID of the actual post. I've updated/edited my question and added some screenshot of the output.